# Convert a SWT/JFace desktop GUI into JavaFX to make it a Web App?

Tags: java, swt, javafx-2, jface, javafx-8

I've read on the [Oracle Java FX Documentation web site](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/) that you can embed SWT into Java FX code.  That's awesome:

I am working with a legacy Java GUI built with SWT and JFace, which gets installed on client machines (Windows 7).  One gripe that my current client has is that they don't want to have to keep installing the application onto every computer they want to use.  They also want to be able to access it from tablets, mobile devices (phones), and laptops, as well as other operating systems (OS X, for example).

Yes, the application should have probably been designed as a web application to begin with, to make my client happier.  However, the code base is large, and a complete rewrite of the code would be horrendously expensive.  We want to now somehow convert this SWT/JFace GUI a web-enabled application with minimal changes.  Can we do this with JavaFX?  Or something else?

Thanks for the replies.

Comment: Have a look at [Eclipse RAP](https://eclipse.org/rap/)

Comment: Thanks greg-449, RAP is what I was after.  I also used WarProduct (http://wiki.eclipse.org/RAP/Equinox_WAR_products) to create a .war file for the project I converted to host it on JBoss EAP.  I'll credit you with the solution if you make your reply an Answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may find [Eclipse RAP](https://eclipse.org/rap/) can run the SWT code as a web application.